# Отправка данных из поля нажатием на Enter

Tags: html, form

Какие есть варианты реализации возможности, чтобы при вводе данных в поле на сайте их можно было отравлять не только кнопкой, но и нажатием Enter?

Comment: Перехватываете событие нажатия на кнопку и дальше обрабатываете как вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Самый правильный вариант — обернуть все поля ввода (и кнопку тоже) в тег [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Далее при необходимости можно подписаться на событие [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) (элемента `<form>`), которое будет возникать и при нажатии на кнопку, и при нажатии Enter.

Обратите внимание, что [действие по умолчанию при отправке формы](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action) — отправка запроса с последующей перезагрузкой страницы, при необходимости можно написать свою логику обработки, не забыв отменить стандартное поведение (вызвав метод [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)).

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  // данный обработчик вызовется и при нажатии на кнопку, и при нажатии enter (когда фокус в <input>)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```